# Pass args directly to function from inherited class

Tags: python, class, inheritance

Right now, I have the following working code (simplified for clarity):

```py
from foo.utils import load_project
    
class Preprocessing:
    def __init__(self, n_jobs):
        self.n_jobs = n_jobs
    
    def get_project(self):
        df = load_project(
            filepath = self.fp,
            n_jobs = self.n_jobs,
        )
        return df

   # ..more functions here
        
        
class Project1(Preprocessing):
    def __init__(self, n_jobs = None):
        self.fp = "path/to/project1"
        Preprocessing.__init__(self, n_jobs=n_jobs)
    
    
class Project2(Preprocessing):
    def __init__(self, n_jobs = None):
        self.fp = "path/to/project2"
        Preprocessing.__init__(self, n_jobs=n_jobs)
```

I can get e.g. `Project1` the following way:

```py
p = Project1(n_jobs=4)
df = p.get_project()
```

Now, I'd like to be able to directly pass the `n_jobs` argument to `get_project`, instead of to `Project1`, meaning:

```py
p = Project1()
df = p.get_project(n_jobs=4)
```

Not sure if there is a trivial way, but I couldn't get it to work. How do I need to modify my classes in order to make this work?

Comment: Not sure why this got downvoted? I'd be happy to revise the question if things are unclear.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is *probably* through optional/keyword arguments.

```
class Preprocessing:
    ...
    
    def get_project(self, n_jobs=None):
        n_jobs = n_jobs if n_jobs is not None else self.n_jobs
        df = load_project(
            filepath = self.fp,
            n_jobs = self.n_jobs,
        )
        return df
```

Like this, if you pass n_jobs to get_project, it uses that. If you don't pass anything, it uses the class' variable instead.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, your use of the optional kwarg made me try again to get it working without having to pass `n_jobs` to the child class at all (see my answer). Very sorry if this intent was not clear in my original question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use descriptor

```
class Descriptor(object): 
  
    def __init__(self, name =''): 
        self.name = name 
  
    def __get__(self, obj, objtype): 
        return "the name is {}".format(self.name) 
  
    def __set__(self, obj, name): 
        if isinstance(name, str): 
            self.name = name 
        else: 
            raise TypeError("Name should be string") 
          
class Foo(): 
    name = Descriptor() 
    
g = Foo() 
g.name = "Robocop"
print(g.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought I had already tried the following solution which works, but apparently I had made a mistake somewhere:

```py
from foo.utils import load_project
    
class Preprocessing:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    
    def get_project(self, n_jobs = None):
        df = load_project(
            filepath = self.fp,
            n_jobs = n_jobs,
        )
        return df

   # ..more functions here
        
        
class Project1(Preprocessing):
    def __init__(self):
        self.fp = "path/to/project1"
        Preprocessing.__init__(self)
    
    
class Project2(Preprocessing):
    def __init__(self):
        self.fp = "path/to/project2"
        Preprocessing.__init__(self)
```

Now I can get `Project1` in the intended way:

```py
p = Project1()
df = p.get_project(n_jobs=4)
```